# show an editable event everyday on primefaces schedule

Tags: java, jsf-2, web, primefaces

I am new to Web development, primefaces and stackoverflow. 
I am not even sure if I am allowed to ask generic questions like this here, but I thought I give it a shot since it is driving me crazy!!

So I am using Primefaces schedule component to develop a scheduler. This scheduler reads events for each day from a database, and displays it on the scheduler. of course users are able to add/edit/delete these events by clicking on the date and a dialog opens and user manipulates the data.

It's a shift scheduler, so the number of shifts per day is limited and consistent (and mandatory). For example, everyday has a

```
1) moderator (MM)
2) morning security guard (MSG)
3) afternoon security guard (ASG)
4) overnight security guard (NSG)
```

it's only a matter of who takes these shifts, otherwise these shifts must be filled in 2 days in advance. So what I would like to do is

1) read data from DB and populate the day with those that are already assigned (easy) 
2) if they are not assigned yet, show an empty field (not from database anymore, a view only event)

such as

```
Wednesday     Thursday        Friday    
MM  bob       MM  mike        MM    <empty>
MSG mike      MSG john        MSG   <empty>
ASG john      ASG <empty>     ASG   <empty>
NSG dave      NSG bob         NSG   <empty>
```

here, all those that are assigned already are read from the database, but I have no idea how to display those that are not yet assigned. Note that they are not in the database, they are just in the view until a user clicks on it to assign it to himself.

Any suggestion, peace of code, or any other help would be very much appreciated. Even if you know a better choice (than primefaces), feel free to let me know.

Comment: Why do you have to show all the empty slots on the calendar? Instead, simply show all the assigned slots and the users already know which slots are still empty :). When a user click on a date, open a dialog which contains radio buttons for him to select 1 empty slot for himself. For example, on Thursday, there will be only 1 radio button for `ASG`. On Friday, there are 4 buttons :P.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes 
True ... but that's what I already have. What you said is already implemented. but as a part of requirement of the app, I am asked to eliminate the use of dialog box. I am also asked to this because it is visually easier to find out what spots are empty.
I have gone far to actually populate the database with all those events in advance, but that'll be a very bad practice + slows down the app. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I don't think there is a "clean" way to achieve what you want :P. Still, instead of filling the database with meaningless rows, you can fill the calendar with assigned slots from database. After that, in the Managed bean of that view, just do a while loop to fill up all the empty slots. Use `lazy` schedule and fill up the calendar each time the user change `month` or `week`, etc.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes     
I guess that's the best way to go! I was actually concerned about performance!!! Good to know about lazy loading :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to retrieve the values from database and loop them. When you should have a value for a specific date, and you don't (because not in database) then add an empty one (to the variable in your bean)
Or you could instantiate a whole list of empty entries in your bean (constructor) and when retrieving results from database, loop them and add then (replace the empty one) to you bean variable. That way you end up with a list of empty and filled in spots.
How do you read in these values from database? Is it a list?

Comment: hmmm .... I have got to try this way ! It pretty much matches what Mr.J4mes told me. I was hoping there is a smarter way, but I guess this is as far as we can go. 
Yes it is a list. Let me try it and get back with the result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tried your Roel's suggestion above and worked great:

```
schedulerModel = new LazyScheduleModel(){

  @override
  public void loadEvents(Date start, Date end){
     for(date=start;date<end;date++){//obv psudo
        if(iSinDataBase) 
             showDatainDB();
        else 
             addEvent(new scheduleEvent(title,date,date));
     }
  }

}
```